# OAuth2 for Google API on Python for Contacts

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

Okay, I followed the answer here:
[Is it possible to use "Domain-wide Delegation of Authority" with gdata-python-client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676513/is-it-possible-to-use-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority-with-gdata-python-cl)

However when I run my test I get this:

> oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied

Here's my code:

```
class OAuthToken():
def __init__(self, creds):
    self.creds = creds
def modify_request(self, req):
    if self.creds.access_token_expired or not self.creds.access_token:
        self.creds.refresh(httplib2.Http())
    self.creds.apply(req.headers)

def ListContacts(username):

file    =   open('privatekey.pem','rb')
text    =   file.read()
file.close()
credentials =   SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('somelongnumber@developer.gserviceaccount.com',\
                text,\
                scope=['http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'],\
                prn=username+'@mycompany.com')

gdclient    =   gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='mycompany.com')
gdclient.auth_token =   OAuthToken(credentials)
feed    =   gdclient.GetContacts()
```

All of my other OAuth2 stuff works, it's just the contacts that are causing me grief, so I think I have the API & credentials set up correctly.

I *did* add https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ to my "One or More API Scopes" in the API security, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Amazing what one little letter will do.

Even though the auth path is http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/, the actual path for the credentials has to be https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/

Amateur mistake. Sorry folks.